# Xcode 3.2.6 Release configuration is missing

Tags: iphone

Hello I am trying to submit app to appstore.

I had release option in Xcode.But some setting has been changed and now I am having only debug option. No release ,No distribution .

what Can I do?

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Projects-> Edit Project settings -> Go to Configurations -> Check for available Configuration list. You can also add Configuration you require.....

Hope it helps....

Comment: I am having debug and release in that.. but not in uper left corner..  from where we choose device or simulator :(

Comment: please help.. I m downloading distribution provisioning profile but why it is kind of developer provisioning profile ?

Comment: Same thing happened to me and i Quit Xcode and restarted it and it worked fine.... Try this if it solves your issue

Comment: Ok.. I made the build of its copy.. now I am having Validation[3771:607] *** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool this warning.. do u know abt this?